# Relate different MySQL tables based on "Line order" column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Basically i have different mysql tables and i want to bring a relation based on the "LineNumber" column that those tables have. This is like a relation one-to-many, where the "LineNumber" value of the "father" table determines his many "sons". These tables are created from a txt document that have a hierarchy determined by the lines.

This is an simple example of 2 tables that i have (REGA100 and REGA101), where REGA100 is the "father" and REGA101 is the "son":

"Father" - REGA100:

| Id | Reg | LineNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A100 | 2692 |
| 2 | A100 | 2695 |
| 3 | A100 | 2697 |
| 4 | A100 | 2699 |

"Son" - REGA101:

| Id | Reg | LineNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A101 | 2693 |
| 2 | A101 | 2694 |
| 3 | A101 | 2696 |
| 4 | A101 | 2698 |

Notice that, the first row of the father table (REGA100) is the value 2692 and the next row is 2695, so for the rows with values between those values in the son table (REGA101) which are 2693 and 2694, i need to put the father row value next to them.

So, basically the idea is to output a query like this (REGA101 with the "father" of each row represented in the REGA100 rows):
OUTPUT QUERY:

| Id | Reg | LineNumber | Id | Reg | LineNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A101 | 2693 | 1 | A100 | 2692 |
| 2 | A101 | 2694 | 1 | A100 | 2692 |
| 3 | A101 | 2696 | 2 | A100 | 2695 |
| 4 | A101 | 2698 | 3 | A100 | 2697 |

I tried to explain the better i could but my english is not so good, so Im sorry for any difficulties and i can fix or explain better certain parts of my text.
I also have a python script that can handle pretty well this situation using dataframes, but I need to do this in a query if possible. (If the script is needed i can edit and post it).

Edit:
This is an example of query that i have tried, it brings the results as i expect the output to be, but when i have big tables to try, the number of rows in the resultant query doesnt match what i need (the result query must have the same amount of rows of the "son" table). Anyway, this is what i have tried:

[image: Query]

(The declaration_id is just an column that refers to the document where the information was read, so its irrelevant to the query).

Im trying to figure out what is the problem with this query and i think is related to the inner join to the same table, but i dont know what else to do..

Comment: [Edit] your question and include your best attempt of such a query. Explain what the problem with it was.

Comment: Know that a table called REGA101 with a column called Reg and a value of A101is highly suggestive of poor schema design.

Comment: @Strawberry those are just for example, my tables doesnt have those columns, i just tough this would be better for visualization.

Comment: Even so, it still seems likely that this design could be optimised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select
  c.id, c.reg, c.linenumber,
  x.id, x.reg, x.linenumber
from (
  select f1.*, coalesce(f2.linenumber, 10000) as nextfather
  from rega100 f1
  left join rega100 f2 on f1.id + 1 = f2.id
) x
inner join rega101 c
  on c.linenumber > x.linenumber and c.linenumber < x.nextfather;
```

Result

```
+------+------+------------+------+------+------------+
| id   | reg  | linenumber | id   | reg  | linenumber |
+------+------+------------+------+------+------------+
|    1 | A101 |       2693 |    1 | A100 |       2692 |
|    2 | A101 |       2694 |    1 | A100 |       2692 |
|    3 | A101 |       2696 |    2 | A100 |       2695 |
|    4 | A101 |       2698 |    3 | A100 |       2697 |
+------+------+------------+------+------+------------+
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83713672bd11c976e25d3e1bc9870372

Explanation

In order to get the right children for 2692, I need to find all numbers greater than 2692 in the child and all numbers less than the next father's number. Next father's number is 2695.

So, first I use this query to get current father and next father's information together.

```
select f1.*, coalesce(f2.linenumber, 10000) as nextfather
from rega100 f1
left join rega100 f2 on f1.id + 1 = f2.id
```

That gives me:

```
+------+------+------------+------------+
| id   | reg  | linenumber | nextfather |
+------+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | A100 |       2692 |       2695 |
|    2 | A100 |       2695 |       2697 |
|    3 | A100 |       2697 |       2699 |
|    4 | A100 |       2699 |      10000 |
+------+------+------------+------------+
```

Just know that the last father has no next father. So, I would typically get NULL for next father. Instead of NULL, I am using a rather big number as a substitute (10,000 in my example).

Then, I join this sub-query with rega101 (children table). For first father, I ask for all rega101 records with line number > 2692 and < 2695. For each row, such matching happens and you get the result you desire.

Comment: The result from this query was the same that i was having with my query, when Im using tables with large amount of data it doesnt bring what i expect, thank you for your help

Comment: @jampzs As your data and schema changes, the query will have to adapt. I understand the schema in your question and data is not a true representative of your real data. If you can shed some light on what issue you are getting with the large amount of data, we can help you better. For the question you posed, seems like the answer is adequate.

Comment: Yeah, I tested your query with a sample that was giving me erros, but it runned ok, i think its something structural in my db, i will try to design it better..

Comment: @jampzs if the answer helped you solve the issue you described, you could put a closure to your question by marking it accepted. You can do so by clicking on a check mark by the answer. You are also welcome to wait for others to answer.